# How to capture all of the groups before and after a specific character

Tags: python, regex, text-processing

I am trying to capture all of the groups before `;`. I also need to capture the last group which does not finish with `;`. Here is my statement and code.

regex:

```
((\*|\/|\)|\(|[-+]\d+|[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+|\w+d?|\+|\-|=|{|}|:=|while|do|if|else|then|skip|or|and|not|>=)+;)+
```

statement:

```
x1:=0; x2:=1; x3:= (x1,x2,+); x4:=5; while {(x4,0,>=)} do {x4:= (x4,1,-); x1:=x2; x2:=x3; x3:= (x1, x2,+)}
```

My regex only captures the first group. I need to capture all groups including the last one.

So the final group should be the following:

```
['x1:=0', 'x2:=1', 'x3:= (x1,x2,+)', 'x4:=5', 'while {(x4,0,>=)} do {x4:= (x4,1,-)', 'x1:=x2', 'x2:=x3', 'x3:= (x1, x2,+)']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two very easy ways to do this. One doesn't even need regex. Here's some code showing two different implementation. The pattern you want is:

`' ?([^;]+);?'`

Example Code:

```
import re

statement = 'x1:=0; x2:=1; x3:= (x1,x2,+); x4:=5; while {(x4,0,>=)} do {x4:= (x4,1,-); x1:=x2; x2:=x3; x3:= (x1, x2,+)}'

#-the quick way
print('Quick way:')
print(state.split('; '))

#-the ~magic~ regex way
print('Regex way:')
pattern = ' ?([^;]+);?'
print(re.compile(pat).findall(state))
```

Output:

```
Quick way:
['x1:=0', 'x2:=1', 'x3:= (x1,x2,+)', 'x4:=5', 'while {(x4,0,>=)} do {x4:= (x4,1,-)', 'x1:=x2', 'x2:=x3', 'x3:= (x1, x2,+)}']
Regex way:
['x1:=0', 'x2:=1', 'x3:= (x1,x2,+)', 'x4:=5', 'while {(x4,0,>=)} do {x4:= (x4,1,-)', 'x1:=x2', 'x2:=x3', 'x3:= (x1, x2,+)}']
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can just use split:

```
ting = 'x1:=0; x2:=1; x3:= (x1,x2,+); x4:=5; while {(x4,0,>=)} do {x4:= (x4,1,-); x1:=x2; x2:=x3; x3:= (x1, x2,+)}'
ting2 = ting.split(';')
# ['x1:=0', ' x2:=1', ' x3:= (x1,x2,+)', ' x4:=5', ' while {(x4,0,>=)} do {x4:= (x4,1,-)', ' x1:=x2', ' x2:=x3', ' x3:= (x1, x2,+)}']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's way more logical than I did. After I split from the semi colon, I used the modified version of my regex to get all of the characters one by one.